# Funciones en Jtable Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas necesito saber como poner una funcion en un Jtable en Java para que en una columna descuente un porcentaje especifico de otra columna, ejemplo que la tabla tenga dos columnas que en la columna 1 se pone un monto y la columna dos descuente un porcentaje automaticamente de la columna 1, la idea es para hacer una nomina y que al poner el salario del empleado en las otras columnas descuente automaticamente los porcentajes que se descuentan de dicho salario por seguro, entre otros. Gracias espero ser claro y obtener una ayuda.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para comprender mejor tu problema. Tal como está ahora, no se entiende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que ni tu pregunta, ni la manera que existe para cambiar los datos de una `JTable` son demasiado claras, pero vamos a intentarlo.

---

Aqui tienes un MVCE para que modifiques como necesites. (comentarios en el código) que permite el cambio de los datos y recalcula la 3a columna en funcion de las dos primeras como pedías.

**NOTAS:**

- He realizado las pruebas en Eclipse: ten en cuenta que el IDE (en tu caso NetBeans) no influye en como trabajan las technologias (en este caso Swing).
- He realizado la operacion de `precio * cantidad`, pero pasar a descuento como tu quieres es muy facil...

---

## MVCE

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // nombre de las columnas
    Object nombreColumnas[] = { "Precio" , "Cantidad", "Total" };
    // datos iniciales SIN TOTALES
    String datos[][] = {
            { "10.33", "2", "" },
            { "30.5", "8", "" } };

    
    // creamos la tabla con los datos de ejemplo
    final JTable table = new JTable(datos, nombreColumnas);

    // calculamos los totales antes de mostrar la tabla
    table.setModel(calculatTotales(table.getModel()));
    
    // y le añadimos un listener
    //
    // ¡¡¡¡OJO!!!!!
    // 
    // El listener se lo ponemos AL MODELO DE DATOS, no a la tabla!!!!
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        // para evitar concurrencias
        boolean active = false;
        
        // evento general
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) 
        {
            // si no tiene una ejecucion y hemos modificado
            if (!active && e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                active = true;
                
                // recogemos el modelo
                TableModel modelo = table.getModel();
                // y le ponemos el nuevo con los totales calculados
                
                table.setModel(calculatTotales(modelo));
                active = false;
            }
        }
    });

    // jframe standard para enseñar la tabla
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    // apartde de hacer scrill sirve para 
    // mostrar los titulos de las columnas
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static TableModel calculatTotales(TableModel datos) {
    for (int x = 0; x < datos.getRowCount(); x ++) {
        String valor = null; 
        try {
            valor = String.valueOf((Double.valueOf((String) datos.getValueAt(x, 0)) * (Integer.valueOf((String) datos.getValueAt(x, 1)))));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        datos.setValueAt(valor, x, 2);
    }
    
    return datos;
}
```

---

## RESULTADO:

**inicial**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**una vez modificado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero aquí ya estas definiendo los valores en el código de las columnas precio y cantidad y lo que hiciste fue multiplicar esta bien el ejemplo pero lo que yo quiero es sacar un porcentaje, en si la tabla es para una nomina como dice arriba y como en las nominas a los empleados se le descuentas cosas del sueldo lo que quiero es que cada columna haga esas operaciones de forma automática restar x porcentaje de x monto y muestre el total, no se si eso sea posible.

Comment: @JesusRC sacar **un porcentage también es multiplicar**. Mira la edición que he hecho, donde no informo los totales. Le pongo solo datos y  creo la tabla, despues dinamicamente los calculo antes de mostrarlos. En el ejemplo tienes todo lo necesario para hacer lo que pides, coge los datos de donde necesites (no se de donde te vienen), llena la tabla con ellos, crea la tabla, coge el modelo y calcula los campos para volver a llenar la tabla... Como te digo, no es intuitivo lo de los modelos, pero una vez lo pillas es facil. Animo! solo tienes que ponerle un poco de tu parte `;)`